# Startup dependency on a singleton EJB in a different module, but in the same ear file

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have an EJB ear application deployment with two jars. The first jar has a singleton called Bootstrap:

The second jar has many singletons that need to be started only after the Bootstrap singleton initializes.

For example, the application.xml in the ear file has this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <application-name>service</application-name>
  <display-name>xxxx-ear</display-name>
  <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
  <module>
    <ejb>mainapp.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      ...
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>bootstrap.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

The bootstrap.jar has a singleton EJB of the form:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Bootstrap {
   ...
}
```

The mainapp.jar has many singletons, for example one of them:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@DependsOn("Bootstrap")
public class JobManager
{
    ...
}
```

Things seem to work and the application seems to be properly deployed when the @DependsOn() annotation is not present on the JobManager bean. However, when the @DependsOn annotation is added, the application does not deploy properly. Without the complete initialization of the Bootstrap class, it is not guarenteed that the JobManager bean will work correctly as it depends upon many objects that are initialized by the JobManager bean.

The question I have is how do I express dependency on a singleton bean in another jar file (thus different module name) in the same application ear file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@DependsOn("bootstrap.jar#Bootstrap")
```

[source](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tejb_ssb.html)